# Drag and Drop to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I'm dragging an html element and dropped to a canvas, took the location where released and plot the object at same location at canvas. But showing at the different location. See my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/YXxsH/2/).

Script

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("graphCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.lineWidth = 2;
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    document.getElementById("graphCanvas").getContext("2d").drawImage(document.getElementById(data), 
        ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="graphCanvas" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" height=300 width=300 style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <img id="img1" src="http://static.tumblr.com/vcbmwcj/foumiteqs/arrow_up_alt1.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Updated code is http://jsfiddle.net/YXxsH/5/. Calculations are done with `pageX` and `pageY` and image `offset` values.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind that variable it's unused. Issue is still not fixed

Comment: Already clarified in the question, dropping at one place rendering at another place.

Comment: That's nice. But still problem is hidden. Try increase canvas width or height and drop again(Increase up to scroll bar shown).

Comment: @ViliusL Is it easy to make the dropped elements moveable inside the canvas?  So a user can re-position them after its dropped?

Comment: @sjs you have to save or know element position, catch user drag so you know change of x and y coordinates, clear canvas, draw canvas background if you need, redraw wanted element with new position.